# Unable to Change media queries

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries, responsive

i am creating a project in which we are storing user's data...

I used a table format,
In that i want to keep same layout for all devices (mobile,tab, laptop).
I don't want mobile and tab layout (responsiveness).

For all viewers it should be laptop/pc type layout (mobile and tab viewers also)

Your help will help me alot...

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif
}

a {
  margin: 0;
  transition: all .4s;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s;
  -o-transition: all .4s;
  -moz-transition: all .4s
}

a:focus {
  outline: 0 !important
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0
}

p {
  margin: 0
}

li,
ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none
}

input {
  display: block;
  outline: 0;
  border: none !important
}

textarea {
  display: block;
  outline: 0
}

input:focus,
textarea:focus {
  border-color: transparent !important
}

button {
  outline: 0 !important;
  border: none;
  background: 0 0
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer
}

iframe {
  border: none !important
}

.limiter {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto
}

.container-table100 {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #c4d3f6;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 33px 30px
}

.wrap-table100 {
  width: 960px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden
}

.table {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  margin: 0
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .table {
    display: block
  }
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
  background: #fff
}

.row.header {
  color: #fff;
  background: #6c7ae0
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .row {
    display: block
  }
  .row.header {
    padding: 0;
    height: 0
  }
  .row.header .cell {
    display: none
  }
  .row .cell:before {
    font-family: Poppins, sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: 700 !important;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: grey;
    line-height: 1.2;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: unset !important;
    margin-bottom: 13px;
    content: attr(data-title);
    min-width: 98px;
    display: block
  }
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .cell {
    display: block
  }
}

.row .cell {
  font-family: Poppins, sans-serif !important;
  font-weight: 400 !important;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #666;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: unset !important;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f2f2
}

.row.header .cell {
  font-family: Poppins, sans-serif !important;
  font-weight: 400 !important;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: unset !important;
  padding-top: 19px;
  padding-bottom: 19px
}

.row .cell:nth-child(1) {
  width: 240px;
  padding-left: 40px
}

.row .cell:nth-child(2) {
  width: 240px;
  padding-left: 20px
}

.row .cell:nth-child(3) {
  width: 240px;
  padding-left: 20px
}

.row .cell:nth-child(4) {
  width: 240px;
  padding-left: 0
}

.row,
.table {
  width: 100% !important
}

.row:hover {
  background-color: #ececff;
  cursor: pointer
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
  .row {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
    padding-bottom: 18px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    margin: 0
  }
  .row .cell {
    border: none;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-top: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 16px
  }
  .row .cell:nth-child(1) {
    padding-left: 30px
  }
  .row .cell {
    font-family: Poppins, sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: 400 !important;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #555;
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-weight: unset !important
  }
  .cell,
  .row,
  .table {
    width: 100% !important
  }
}
```

```html
<div class=limiter>
  <div class=container-table100>
    <div class=wrap-table100>
      <div class=table id=adi45>
        <div class="row header">
          <div class="cell hd">Full Name</div>
          <div class="cell hd">Email Address</div>
          <div class="cell hd">Username</div>
          <div class="cell hd">Password</div>
        </div>
        <div class=row>
          <div class=cell data-title="Full Name">Joseph Smith</div>
          <div class=cell data-title=Age>27</div>
          <div class=cell data-title="Job Title">Project Manager</div>
          <div class=cell data-title=Location>Somerville, MA</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. What is preventing you from changing the media queries?

Comment: If you want exactly the same layout for sll viewport sizes why are you using media queries? If everything is defined in relative terms (e.g.%) then you should get the same layout for all. Perhaps you could describe what the problem is in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

The requirement is that the layout look the same regardless of viewport dimensions.

[image]

But the CSS contains several media queries which alter the layout to a block rather than a table-like layout on narrower devices.

I don't know why those are there if the same layout is required for all, so this snippet removes the media queries as a first step.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif
}

a {
  margin: 0;
  transition: all .4s;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s;
  -o-transition: all .4s;
  -moz-transition: all .4s
}

a:focus {
  outline: 0 !important
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0
}

p {
  margin: 0
}

li,
ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none
}

input {
  display: block;
  outline: 0;
  border: none !important
}

textarea {
  display: block;
  outline: 0
}

input:focus,
textarea:focus {
  border-color: transparent !important
}

button {
  outline: 0 !important;
  border: none;
  background: 0 0
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer
}

iframe {
  border: none !important
}

.limiter {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto
}

.container-table100 {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #c4d3f6;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 33px 30px
}

.wrap-table100 {
  width: 960px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden
}

.table {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  margin: 0
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
  background: #fff
}

.row.header {
  color: #fff;
  background: #6c7ae0
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell
}

.row .cell {
  font-family: Poppins, sans-serif !important;
  font-weight: 400 !important;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #666;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: unset !important;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f2f2
}

.row.header .cell {
  font-family: Poppins, sans-serif !important;
  font-weight: 400 !important;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: unset !important;
  padding-top: 19px;
  padding-bottom: 19px
}

.row .cell:nth-child(1) {
  width: 240px;
  padding-left: 40px
}

.row .cell:nth-child(2) {
  width: 240px;
  padding-left: 20px
}

.row .cell:nth-child(3) {
  width: 240px;
  padding-left: 20px
}

.row .cell:nth-child(4) {
  width: 240px;
  padding-left: 0
}

.row,
.table {
  width: 100% !important
}

.row:hover {
  background-color: #ececff;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<div class=limiter>
  <div class=container-table100>
    <div class=wrap-table100>
      <div class=table id=adi45>
        <div class="row header">
          <div class="cell hd">Full Name</div>
          <div class="cell hd">Email Address</div>
          <div class="cell hd">Username</div>
          <div class="cell hd">Password</div>
        </div>
        <div class=row>
          <div class=cell data-title="Full Name">Joseph Smith</div>
          <div class=cell data-title=Age>27</div>
          <div class=cell data-title="Job Title">Project Manager</div>
          <div class=cell data-title=Location>Somerville, MA</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Luckily almost everything remaining in the CSS is defined in relative units (%) so all viewport sizes show a table. However, on the narrowest devices not all the width of the table fits in - while words are wrapped this is done on whole words only so there is some spillage on the right hand side. For example:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif
}

a {
  margin: 0;
  transition: all .4s;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s;
  -o-transition: all .4s;
  -moz-transition: all .4s
}

a:focus {
  outline: 0 !important
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0
}

p {
  margin: 0
}

li,
ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none
}

input {
  display: block;
  outline: 0;
  border: none !important
}

textarea {
  display: block;
  outline: 0
}

input:focus,
textarea:focus {
  border-color: transparent !important
}

button {
  outline: 0 !important;
  border: none;
  background: 0 0
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer
}

iframe {
  border: none !important
}

.limiter {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto
}

.container-table100 {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #c4d3f6;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 33px 30px
}

.wrap-table100 {
  width: 960px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden
}

.table {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  margin: 0
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
  background: #fff
}

.row.header {
  color: #fff;
  background: #6c7ae0
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell
}

.row .cell {
  font-family: Poppins, sans-serif !important;
  font-weight: 400 !important;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #666;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: unset !important;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f2f2
}

.row.header .cell {
  font-family: Poppins, sans-serif !important;
  font-weight: 400 !important;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: unset !important;
  padding-top: 19px;
  padding-bottom: 19px
}

.row .cell:nth-child(1) {
  width: 240px;
  padding-left: 40px
}

.row .cell:nth-child(2) {
  width: 240px;
  padding-left: 20px
}

.row .cell:nth-child(3) {
  width: 240px;
  padding-left: 20px
}

.row .cell:nth-child(4) {
  width: 240px;
  padding-left: 0
}

.row,
.table {
  width: 100% !important
}

.row:hover {
  background-color: #ececff;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<div class=limiter>
  <div class=container-table100>
    <div class=wrap-table100>
      <div class=table id=adi45>
        <div class="row header">
          <div class="cell hd">Full Name</div>
          <div class="cell hd">Email Address</div>
          <div class="cell hd">Username</div>
          <div class="cell hd">Password</div>
        </div>
        <div class=row>
          <div class=cell data-title="Full Name">Joseph Smith</div>
          <div class=cell data-title=Age>27</div>
          <div class=cell data-title="Job Title">Project Manager</div>
          <div class=cell data-title=Location>Somerville, MA</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Which, on a device of width 360px for example, ends up with something like this:
[image]

It's probably not going to help the user if we hyphenate the words to make them fit - though that is an option. Another option is to realise that though most units in the CSS are relative to viewport size, the definition of font size is not, so the words are too big to fit horizontally.

One thing we can do is make the font size relative to viewport width so everything will fit. This may mean on very large screens the size will become maybe too large. This is a matter for you to decide. You could limit the font size by using the CSS min function. This snippet sets font size relative to viewport width but not above 10px. Then actual sizes are set relative to that - e.g. 18px becomes 1.8em (so it's easy to see the conversion).

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif
}

a {
  margin: 0;
  transition: all .4s;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s;
  -o-transition: all .4s;
  -moz-transition: all .4s
}

a:focus {
  outline: 0 !important
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0
}

p {
  margin: 0
}

li,
ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none
}

input {
  display: block;
  outline: 0;
  border: none !important
}

textarea {
  display: block;
  outline: 0
}

input:focus,
textarea:focus {
  border-color: transparent !important
}

button {
  outline: 0 !important;
  border: none;
  background: 0 0
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer
}

iframe {
  border: none !important
}

.limiter {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto
}

.container-table100 {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #c4d3f6;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 33px 30px;
  font-size: min(2vw, 10px); /* ADDED */
}

.wrap-table100 {
  width: 960px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden
}

.table {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  margin: 0
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
  background: #fff
}

.row.header {
  color: #fff;
  background: #6c7ae0
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell
}

.row .cell {
  font-family: Poppins, sans-serif !important;
  font-weight: 400 !important;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-size: 1.5em; /* ADDED */
  color: #666;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: unset !important;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f2f2
}

.row.header .cell {
  font-family: Poppins, sans-serif !important;
  font-weight: 400 !important;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-size: 1.8em; /* ADDED */
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: unset !important;
  padding-top: 19px;
  padding-bottom: 19px
}

.row .cell:nth-child(1) {
  width: 240px;
  padding-left: 40px
}

.row .cell:nth-child(2) {
  width: 240px;
  padding-left: 20px
}

.row .cell:nth-child(3) {
  width: 240px;
  padding-left: 20px
}

.row .cell:nth-child(4) {
  width: 240px;
  padding-left: 0
}

.row,
.table {
  width: 100% !important
}

.row:hover {
  background-color: #ececff;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<div class=limiter>
  <div class=container-table100>
    <div class=wrap-table100>
      <div class=table id=adi45>
        <div class="row header">
          <div class="cell hd">Full Name</div>
          <div class="cell hd">Email Address</div>
          <div class="cell hd">Username</div>
          <div class="cell hd">Password</div>
        </div>
        <div class=row>
          <div class=cell data-title="Full Name">Joseph Smith</div>
          <div class=cell data-title=Age>27</div>
          <div class=cell data-title="Job Title">Project Manager</div>
          <div class=cell data-title=Location>Somerville, MA</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Having said all of that, given you want the same layout on all viewport sizes, and given the data does seem to be a table (though the entries given don't match the headings) it may be just easier to start again and set it as an HTML table.